# Isometries of the complex projective space for the Fubini Study metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, fibre-bundles, isometry-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$I am trying to understand a geometric proof in our mathematical quantum mechanics lecture regarding Wigner's theorem in finite dimensions. We have already shown that it suffices to study the isometries of the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P^n$. On $\mathbb{C}P^n$ we consider the Fubini-Study metric such that $\pi:S^{2n+1}\to \mathbb{C}P^n$ is a Riemannian submersion and $\Phi:\mathbb{C}P^n\to\mathbb{C}P^n$ is an isometry. Since the unitary group $U(n)$ acts transitively on $S^{2n+1}$ we may assume that $\Phi$ has a fixed point $\Phi([v])=[v]$. Then $I:=T_{[v]}\Phi\in \text{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(T_{[v]}\mathbb{C}P^n)$ is an orthogonal isometry. Why does $I$ map complex lines to complex lines? This is equivalent to $I$ being complex linear or antilinear which then would prove that $\Phi$ is induced by a unitary or antiunitary map.

Another attempt I came up with is trying to understand when a diffeomorphism $\Phi$ of the base space $M$ of a principal fibre bundle $\pi:P\to M$ with typical fibre $G$ lifts to a diffeomorphism $\widetilde{\Phi}$ the total space $P$. This is equivalent to the pullpack $\Phi^\ast P$ being equivalent to $P$. If $\Phi^\ast P$ is equivalent to $P$ not only as a fibre bundle but also as a fibre bundle then $\Phi$ even lifts to a $G$-equivariant map. Since in the case above I already know that the isometries that lift are either equivariant with respect to $z.v:=zv$, for $z\in S^1,\;v\in S^{2n+1}$, or are equivariant for the action $z.v:=zv$ one the first bundle and $z.v:=\overline{z}v$ on the second. But the problem is the the set of bundle equivalences $\text{Bun}(\mathbb{C}P^n,S^1)=H^2(\mathbb{C}P^n,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ and my attempts to explicitly construct an equivalence $\varphi:\Phi^\ast S^{2n+1}\to S^{2n+1}$ failed. Is there some general fact on isometries one could use here?

Also the Fubini-Study metric is the unique $\SU(n)$-invariant metric on the symmetric space $\mathbb{C}P^n=\SU(n)/\mathrm{S}(\mathrm{U}(1)\times \mathrm{U}(n-1))$. Therefore we already know that the isometry group is a compact Lie group with identity component $\SU(n)$. Is there a way we can show that there are exactly two connected components? This would also solve my problem.

Comment: To see that $I$ maps complex lines to complex lines observe that $\Phi$ leaves the cut locus of $v$ invariant which is just $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$. points in this $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ are exactly complex lines in the tangent space to $v$. By continuity $I$ must be complex linear or complex antilinear as you say and the rest follows rather easily.